# Can we send email through gmail or yahoo clients in iPhone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send email through gmail or other message clients,is it possible in iOS.
I searched a lot but didn't find anything.
I don't want to use the default composer to send mail.I wants user to choose whether they want to send emails from the default mfmailcomposeviewcontroll or can send through gmail,yahoo.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways in which 3rd-party developers may offer this functionality -- regardless of the manner selected, it is up to the 3rd-party vendor to decide how much (if any) of these methods are implemented and documented in the public domain as accessible to other applications or users.  Ultimately you will need to consult the target product's documentation or support channels to determine if such mechanisms exist.  While this is neither an exhaustive list, nor it is a list of formally supported mechanisms for achieving your goal, it should give you some insight into what to go research or ask additional questions about:

**Option 1: Open URL Schemes**
iOS Developers can register their applications to respond to a URL scheme like "tel://" or "sms://" or "http://".  If vendors register a URL scheme it will be visible in the app's info.plist.  While it won't speak to the format of any parameters you need to pass, the vendor's documentation or support personnel may be able to shine a light on those capabilities.  For the HTTP scheme, iOS' MobileSafari.app is registered to respond -- the well-formed NSURL that gets passed to Safari is used as the URL to which Safari navigates when launched.

**Option 2: 3rd-party SDK**
Other vendors may elect to make an SDK available that you can implement in your app.  Google Drive, Dropbox, and Facebook are all great examples.  To incorporate these cloud filesystems or social capabilities in your own apps, you can register as a developer and follow install guides to both adopt their SDK and leverage the functionality the SDK provides.

As for your specific question, it appears as though Google's official Gmail app does have an undocumented URL Scheme that the community has discovered, reverse-engineered, and written up.  While I **VERY STRONGLY DISCOURAGE** use of undocumented app capabilities there is nothing preventing you from using this functionality.  Keep in mind that because this is undocumented, there is a distinct possibility that the feature could be removed, changed, or otherwise made unavailable in future builds that can leave your own app in a bit of a bind.  Furthermore, for those of your users that do not have the Gmail app installed would not be able to leverage this URL Scheme and could lead to a poor user experience.  All that said, with the caveats above, Tom Scotland has written up a series of blog posts on the Gmail app's URL scheme and updates to the scheme as a function of the rest of the Google constellation of iOS apps - http://tom.scogland.com/blog/2013/01/29/gmail-url-scheme/

Yahoo Mail is a separate issue -- As far as I can tell, this app offers neither of these access options, however I'll leave the digging as an exercise for the OP.

Again, I encourage you to use `MFMailComposerViewController` instead of unofficial or unapproved app capabilities so as to limit your own app's exposure to changes beyond your control.